# PyQt4: How to specify the length and width of the squares of the QGridLayout

Tags: python, pyqt4

I'm wondering about the length and width of the row in PyQt4 and can only find methods to ask the number of them, or to set the geometry of the whole layout but not to see or specify the length of each square. I have conceptualized my draft as to accomodate as 125x125 grid.

On a separate but not completly unrelated, is there another way to order widget in the Window other than (H/V/Grid)layouts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of Layouts is to arrange them with respect to each other.

If you want to have fixed widget sizes and position, you can position them yourself, manually:

```
w = QWidget()
w.resize(800, 800)

i = QWidget(w)
i.move(200, 200)
i.setFixedSize(400, 400)
#alternatively: i.setGeometry(200, 200, 400, 400)

i.setStyleSheet("QWidget {background-color:blue}")
w.show()
```

Comment: Setting the size of the grid rows and columns, and having widgets 'fill' to the size of the cell is a really common use for layouts. It surprises me that qt doesn't have a built in method to accomplish this.

Comment: because it’s bad practice. Qt will know what size those cells, rows and columns have. you don’t. do you know which width some text has in the user’s theme font? what paddings the theme has? what if (s)he has an accessibility feature that makes text huge? generally: if you don’t draw every pixel in your widget manually, you have no business in defining its size.

Comment: Its not bad practice, its standard practice in modern UI frameworks. You set the theme options, its your program.

Comment: do you have any counter arguments regarding my points on how it’s bad practice? if not, my points still stand, and it is.

Comment: HTML, WPF, winforms, among others have this feature built in and is the primary suggestion in documentation. This shows it is standard practice. Its done this way to provides uniform spacing for all elements. 
Your primary argument, that "we don't know the theme spacing, font, etc" was already refuted because programmers are able, and usually do, control the theme. 
Also, making an assertion, then claiming you're right because no one refuted you is a burden of proof fallacy.

Comment: no. i didn’t make a claim that i refuse to prove. i proved it by explaining how the alternatives are inadequate. now if *you claim* that they are, in fact, adequate, *you* have the burden of proof.